# Using Label in grub on Debian 9

Tags: debian, grub2, grub, boot-loader, grub2-mkconfig

I installed my server with Debian 9 and Grub with a LABEL. In my `/etc/fstab` I see My label as followed:

```
LABEL=root  /       ext4        errors=remount-ro       0   1
/dev/sr0    /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto         0   0
```

But I see this in my `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-3-amd64 root=**/dev/sda1** ro single
```

How can I change the device to my Label ?

Update:
**/boot/grub/grub.cfg**

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  0a0edac0-c3bd-40bf-b286-30b0d587c949
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0a0edac0-c3bd-40bf-b286-30b0d587c949
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=5
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=5
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
}
set linux_gfx_mode=
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-0a0edac0-c3bd-40bf-b286-30b0d587c949' {
    load_video
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  0a0edac0-c3bd-40bf-b286-30b0d587c949
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0a0edac0-c3bd-40bf-b286-30b0d587c949
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux 4.9.0-6-amd64 ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-6-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro  quiet
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-6-amd64
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-0a0edac0-c3bd-40bf-b286-30b0d587c949' {
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.9.0-6-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.9.0-6-amd64-advanced-0a0edac0-c3bd-40bf-b286-30b0d587c949' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  0a0edac0-c3bd-40bf-b286-30b0d587c949
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0a0edac0-c3bd-40bf-b286-30b0d587c949
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.9.0-6-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-6-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro  quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-6-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.9.0-6-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.9.0-6-amd64-recovery-0a0edac0-c3bd-40bf-b286-30b0d587c949' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  0a0edac0-c3bd-40bf-b286-30b0d587c949
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0a0edac0-c3bd-40bf-b286-30b0d587c949
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.9.0-6-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-6-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro single
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-6-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.9.0-3-amd64-advanced-0a0edac0-c3bd-40bf-b286-30b0d587c949' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  0a0edac0-c3bd-40bf-b286-30b0d587c949
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0a0edac0-c3bd-40bf-b286-30b0d587c949
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-3-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro  quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-3-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.9.0-3-amd64-recovery-0a0edac0-c3bd-40bf-b286-30b0d587c949' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  0a0edac0-c3bd-40bf-b286-30b0d587c949
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0a0edac0-c3bd-40bf-b286-30b0d587c949
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-3-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro single
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-3-amd64
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass root file system by label to linux kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406325/pass-root-file-system-by-label-to-linux-kernel)

Comment: Seems to me it's about how to use the LABEL syntax to specify the root filesystem in the *kernel command line*. According to the `/etc/fstab` example in the question, @Noob already knows how to use it there. The suggested duplicate includes examples and mentions the caveat that the LABEL syntax is really parsed by the initramfs, not the kernel itself; so it will only work if initramfs is being used.

Comment: My /etc/fstab already contains a valid LABEL. But the label is not added to my /boot/grub/grub.cfg file. If I update my grub with update-grub it contains /dev/sda1 instead of LABEL=root.

Answer (score 4):

Use `blkid` or `e2label /dev/sda1` to get the partition label then replace it in your `fstab`, the `root` option in `grub.cfg` file is different, it is used to set the root file system.

Add the following lines to your `/etc/defaut/grub` :

```
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
GRUB_ENABLE_LINUX_LABEL=true
```

Then edit the 2 lines in your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` as follows:

```
search --no-floppy --label root --set=root
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-3-amd64 root=LABEL=root ro single
```

[Debian: Labels](https://wiki.debian.org/fstab#Labels)

[manpages: e2label](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/e2fsprogs/e2label.8.en.html)

Comment: Added the grub.cfg as requested

Comment: @Noob To get the `grub.cfg` generated automatically you need to edit the `10_linux` file and `/usr/lib/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib` See here: https://techpatterns.com/forums/about1575.html and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1530532

Comment: I know that I have to do that on that file. But I can not believe that I am the only one with this error and that this does not have a easy fix. There must be something a option to enable label right ?